# iOS constraints: 4 Buttons

Tags: ios7, nslayoutconstraint

I would like to place 4 buttons on the screen. They should be all of the same height and width. The margin between the buttons should be 35px and the outter margin to the views border should be 20px.

Now the buttons should be scaling to the different sizes of the screen. But all my tries with the constrains have failed.

Does somebody know how to use them properly?

layout:

```
---------------
|             |
|   x     x   |
|             |
|   x     x   |
|             |
---------------
```

X are the buttons

Comment: Do the buttons need to fill the entire space (rectangular) or are they some square buttons?

Comment: The size of the buttons and of the margins should scale with the screen size. But the margins should scale slower than the buttons.

Comment: I don't understand. Reading your question, only the buttons must scale, and the inner margin are 35px. (fixed) and the outer one are 20px. (fixed), is it the result you want?

Comment: Yeah, the margins should stay the same. I got it wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result you want is the one presented below, please follow the steps:

[image]
[image]

> Always keep in mind this method. Design your view as-it-should-render in your storyboard (600x600) and **then** apply your constraints.

- Position your four buttons as expected for a 600x600px. view:

[image]

- Select all buttons, then choose "Equal Width" and "Equal Height" constraint in the lower Constraint helper:

[image]

- Drag-n-drop from B1 to B2 with Ctrl key pressed, release and select "Horizontal Spacing". Do the same between B3 and B4.

[image]

- Repeat the previous step with B1/B3 and B2/B4 but choose "Vertical Spacing".
- For B1, attach-it to 20px. from left and top bounds as presented below:

> Deselect *Constraint to margins* before applying constraint.

[image]

- Do the same for B2 (top/right), B3 (left/bottom) and B4 (right/bottom).

You're all set, your view will now scale appropriately, no matter what's the screen size.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I hope they improve the constraints system.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a program to calculate the sizes of the buttons. First, get your screen width, say 320. Then: 320 = 20 + button width + 35 + button width + 20
2 * button width = 245. button width = 122.5.

The same would apply for the height.

Comment: This method does not use constraints and is harder to use and debug.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1) Add a 1x1 view which has a background color which is clear and add constraints which center it relative to the containing view. This gives you a point in the center.

2) For the left buttons, set the trailing distance to the 1x1 view as 17.5.

3) For the right buttons. set the leading distance to the 1x1 view as 17.5.

4) For the top buttons, set the bottom distance to the 1x1 view as 17.5.

5) For the bottom buttons, set the top distance to the 1x1 view as 17.5.

This gives you the buttons relative to this 1x1 view. You can move this up or down now if you want the buttons at the top or bottom etc... Now you want to handle the scaling of the width.

6) Add an aspect ratio for the buttons which meets your needs. 1:1 for square etc.

7) For the left buttons, set the leading distance to the containing view to be 20pts.

8) For the right buttons, set the trailing distance to the containing view to be 20pts.

As you have the aspect ratio set, the buttons should scale width and height proportionally to satisfy the 20pt constraint and constraint to the 1x1 center point.